# Class DoubleAnimation - Animation is very fast with longer text

Tags: c#, wpf

Follow code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_Notice.MostrarAviso"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_Notice"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Notice" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <!--...-->
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Background="Black">
            <Canvas Canvas.Bottom="0" ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" Background="Red" Height="97" Width="300">
                <TextBlock FontSize="70" Name="tbmarquee" Height="74" FontFamily="Arial Black" Foreground="White" Canvas.Top="10"></TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Quick animation:**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    canMain.Width = ActualWidth;
    tbmarquee.Text = "Donald Trump announced on Friday a new package of measures against North Korea bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla...";
    UpdateLayout();

    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth,
        To = canMain.ActualWidth,
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2),
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    };

    tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```

Result: (Quick animation)

[image]

**Slow animation:**

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    canMain.Width = ActualWidth;
    tbmarquee.Text = "Donald Trump announced...";
    UpdateLayout();

    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth,
        To = canMain.ActualWidth,
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2),
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
    };

    tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```

Result: (Slow animation)

[image]

When the text is small, the animation is slow, now when the text is long, the animation is fast. How to leave the 2 texts with the same speed?

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try having a formula depending on UI elements size:

```
Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds((tbmarquee.ActualWidth + canMain.ActualWidth) * 0.005)));
```

Note `0.005` is just a random constant, adjust it to increase or decrease speed. Instead of relying on length of the `string` you should rely on size of UI elements since chars have different display size.

Comment: does not work well, the speed is different comparing short and long text.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Could you please provide full working code example of it? So I could run it under exact same conditions you are. I would only need xaml.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Take a look at updated answer. Hope that'll do it for you.